# Instantiate a Generic Type

Tags: java, generics, instantiation

My code is:

```
public class MyClass<T extends MyComponent> {
    private T t;
    public MyClass(){
        t = new T();
    }
}
```

But the compiler don't accept new T(). Is there a way to do this using the constructor MyClass(), without parameters?

Comment: Specify the ``T`` as parameter in the constructor.

Comment: What would happen if your T class does not have an empty constructor?

Comment: My T class has a empty constructor

Comment: *without parameters* can't be done. Get used to it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do

```
public class MyClass<T extends MyComponent> {
    private T t;

    MyClass(Class<T> clazz) throws InstantiationException,
            IllegalAccessException {
        t = clazz.newInstance();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Because of type erasure, the JVM doesn't know what `T` is, so it can't instantiate it.  The workaround is to provide a `Class<T>` and use it to create a new instance:

```
public MyClass(Class<T> clazz)
{
    t = clazz.newInstance();
}
```

You'll have to add catching `IllegalAccessException` and `InstantiationException`.

Answer (score 1):

Not without access to T's class object. Think about it, T could be any subclass of MyComponent, how would you even decide which constructors are available on that particular subclass?

Type erasure means that the compiler silently replaces all "real" references to T with MyComponent.

If you have a reference to Class, you may call `Class#newInstance`, or get a constructor and invoke that.